# string indices must be integers, not str in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating nested dictionary like this using code:
dictionary:

```
{u'Titanic': {'match': [{'category': u'Book'},
                        {'category': u'Movie'},
                        {'category': u'Product'}],
              'score': 100}}
```

Titanic is entity, `book, movie, product` are class. Score no need to consider.

```
        grams_to_check_dict = {}
        grams_to_check_dict['key'] = {}
        #grams_to_check_dict['key']['matches'] = []
        print 'No entities detected'
        print "-"*40
        while(True):
            print '\tDo you want to add Entity Y/N ?'
            print '\t'
            choice = raw_input()
            if choice == 'N' or choice == 'n':
                break
            elif choice == 'Y' or choice == 'y' :
                print '\tEnter Entity : \t'
                Entity =  raw_input()
                #grams_to_check_dict['key'] = Entity
                print '\tHow many class do you want to add for this entity? '
                class_no = int(raw_input())
                for i in range(0, int(class_no)):
                    entity_class =  raw_input()
                    grams_to_check_dict[Entity]['matches'].append({'cateogry': entity_class})
                print 'grams_to_check is , '
                print grams_to_check_dict
                break
```

which gives error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

at line

```
grams_to_check_dict['key']['matches'].append({'cateogry': entity_class})
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the value of `grams_to_check_dict['key']` is `Entity`, that is a String. 
and you threat with it like a dictionary ! with this command `grams_to_check_dict['key']['matches']`

if you want to get `{'user_entered_Entity': {'matches': [{'cateogry': 'one'}, {'cateogry': 'two'}]}}` instead of `{'key': {'matches': [{'cateogry': 'one'}, {'cateogry': 'two'}]}}`
remove the line `grams_to_check_dict['key'] = Entity`
 and change

```
grams_to_check_dict['key']['matches'].append({'cateogry': entity_class})
```

to

```
grams_to_check_dict[Entity]['matches'].append({'cateogry': entity_class})
```

Edit :

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['key']={}
>>> d
{'key': {}}

>>> Entity=raw_input(' enter the key name :')
 enter the key name :newkey

>>> d={'%s'%Entity:{}}
>>> d
{'newkey': {}}
```

Comment: :thanks, but still I could not correct it, can you please tell what should be corrected

Comment: so what you want to do ? also your code is a bit complicated !

Comment: When I comment `grams_to_check_dict['key'] = Entity` it gives this result `{'key': {'matches': [{'cateogry': 'one'}, {'cateogry': 'two'}]}}` . RAther I want `{'user_entered_Entity': {'matches': [{'cateogry': 'one'}, {'cateogry': 'two'}]}}`

Comment: ahan , so just use `grams_to_check_dict[Entity]` instead `rams_to_check_dict['key'] = Entity`.

Comment: thanks @Kasra, but now it gives `KeyError: 'entity_i_type'` at ` grams_to_check_dict[Entity]['matches'].append({'cateogry': entity_class})`

Comment: oops , its because of that you dont define your dictionary before , did you define `rams_to_check_dict` before with `key` as its first key ,and now you want to change it ?

Comment: yes, I define it before, like `grams_to_check_dict['key'] = {}`

Comment: so can you use `grams_to_check_dict[Entity] = {}` instead of that ? you could put it after `Entity =  raw_input()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65346/discussion-between-puncrazy-and-kasra).

Comment: thanks for your time and efforts. but still same error on same line

Comment: you're welcome i like this ;) , did you remove `grams_to_check_dict['key'] = {}` ?

Comment: @puncrazy if you want to have a dictionary like what you want you can define it at the leading of your code , as i say and don't use any assigning at all ! or if you can do this and you need to define your dictionary like `grams_to_check_dict['key'] = {}` then you want to change `key` you need to crate another one and assign it to current